# Errors upgrading .Net core VS2015 solution to VS2017

Tags: visual-studio, migration

In my solution I have a number of projects, one is a web app, others are .net core class library projects and I have one DbProject. After migrating the solution I have received 2 types of error against one of what was a .netCore Class library project. The first states that for my project it's unable to **resolve .NetStandard, Version=v1.6**. I found an article that mentioned going into the project files and removing the reference to the above `<PackageReference Include="NETStandard.Library" Version="1.6.1" />` but none of the project files had this reference in them. The second issue is that I have 2 other projects that are trying to reference this project and it complains with the following:
**Unexpected dependency dataModels.csProj with no version number**

Comment: I have managed to resolve the first issue (unable to resolve .NetStandard, Version = v1.6). This seemed to disappear after I installed the VS2017 Power Tools extension ????? Not sure why this would fix it but hey. I still have my second issue though.

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Comment: I had to create the project from scratch within VS2017, then add all my classes manually. This seemed to solve it. Bit of a pain, but it did the trick.